# How do I find an expert to help with theological science fiction writing?

Tags: fiction, research

I am in the process of writing a theological science fiction novel. My interest in this genre is motivated by reading [Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_%28novel%29) by Frank Herbert and [The Divine Invasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Divine_Invasion) by Phillip K. Dick, in addition to watching the [Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix) movies. My novel may have elements of all three of these.  I desire to touch base with religious studies experts, although the narrative portion of the project would remain my own. I am seeking a relationship with a person whom I could regularly interact with as my project progresses, e.g. the expert informs the writing and the writing informs the expert. How do I find such a person?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project. But I'm a bit curious about why you need a theological scholar. Are you trying to invoke a particular religion?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ask around. I suggest going to your nearest university or theological college and inquiring if they have anyone on their staff who is interested in both science fiction and religion.

Most universities have departments either of theology or religious studies. Theological colleges are engaged in training priests or minsters of religion. Avoid religious training institutions focused on fundamental religion.

There is always a good chance someone on the teaching staff whose interests will include science fiction. Explain what you're trying to do and what role you would like them to play in assisting your writing.

Catholic teaching institutions would be a good choice. Catholics always have had a rich tradition in theology. This can be true of Non-Christian religions too, but it takes more specialized knowledge to work your way into them.

You can seek out the sort of experts you are looking for online by doing internet searches for people who either discuss science fiction, religion and theology or blog about it. You will be able to see what they write and whether they will be the sort of experts you want to consult.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: "Avoid religious training institutions focused on fundamental religion." Why?

Comment: @curiousdannii: Generally speaking, dedicated fundamentalists are not religious scholars in the academic sense, but people deeply knowledgable about a single faith, and disinterested in (if not openly hostile to) broader perspectives. No one there is likely to want to discuss 'alternate reality' faiths, even as fictional entertainment